# Creating selected and clicked event handlers for Qframe

Tags: qt

How can I create an event handler for QFrame such as selected/clicked ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QFrame doesn't expose mouse events directly as signals because that's not really its purpose - it's supposed to be used as a container for other widgets.

If you really want to handle mouse events in a QFrame then you'll have to derive a new class from it and implement the appropriate event handlers, e.g. [mousePressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent).